# How to kill the activity with back button?

Tags: java, android

I accidently discovered this. I have a quiz game, and i have a popup for correct answer, for wrong answer and after the game finish I have a popup for result. BUT, today i went back with back button in the middle of the game, to my home screen (not game home screen, my OS home screen) and the game was still in the background, like every other android app. After a few second my wrong answer popped up. :) Time was up, and automatically the answer was wrong. After that my final result popup went on. So, how can I kill that activity when I press back button? I don't know if you guys need any of my code, but just in case here's my game activity:

```
public class NeogranicenoPetGresaka extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(6000, 1000);

LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    Button bIzlazIzKviza, bOdgovor1, bOdgovor2, bOdgovor3, bOdgovor4;
    TextView question, netacniOdg, score, countdown;
    int brojacPogresnihOdgovora = 0;
    int brojacTacnihOdgovora = 0;
    public static String tacanOdg;

    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nextQuestion();
            brojacVremena.start();
        }
     };
    Runnable mLaunchTaskFinish = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            brojacVremena.cancel();
            finish();
         }
      };


    private class Answer {
        public Answer(String opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        String option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                brojacVremena.cancel();
                brojacTacnihOdgovora = brojacTacnihOdgovora + 5;
                Intent i = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TACANODGOVOR");
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,1200);
            }
        /*else{
            brojacVremena.cancel();
            brojacPogresnihOdgovora++;
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PogresanOdgovor.class);
            i.putExtra("tacanOdgovor", tacanOdg);
            startActivity(i);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);
            }*/
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.neograniceno);

        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        Typeface pitanje = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myriad.ttf");
        bIzlazIzKviza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzlazIzKvizaN);
        netacniOdg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBrojPitanjaN);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanjeN);
        bOdgovor1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN1);
        bOdgovor2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN2);
        bOdgovor3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN3);
        bOdgovor4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOdgovorN4);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSkor2N);
        countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCountdownN);
        bOdgovor1.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor2.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor3.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bOdgovor4.setTypeface(dugmad);
        bIzlazIzKviza.setTypeface(dugmad);
        netacniOdg.setTypeface(dugmad);
        question.setTypeface(pitanje);
        score.setTypeface(dugmad);
        countdown.setTypeface(dugmad);

        nextQuestion(); //startuje prvo pitanje!
        brojacVremena.start();  //startuje brojac vremena
    }


    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            brojacPogresnihOdgovora++;
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PogresanOdgovor.class);
            i.putExtra("tacanOdgovor", tacanOdg);
            startActivity(i);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countdown.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
        }

    public void nextQuestion() {


        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());
            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

            Collections.shuffle(labels);

            tacanOdg = c.getString(2);

            if(brojacPogresnihOdgovora < 20){


        question.setText(c.getString(1));

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
        bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
        bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
        bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
        bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
        bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        netacniOdg.setText("" + brojacPogresnihOdgovora);
        score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);
            }
            else{
                brojacVremena.cancel();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Rezultat.class);
                i.putExtra("noviRezultat", brojacTacnihOdgovora);
                startActivity(i);
                String brojacTacnihOdgovoraString = String.valueOf(brojacTacnihOdgovora);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish,4000);
                //SwarmLeaderboard.submitScore(6863, brojacTacnihOdgovora);
                HeyzapLib.submitScore(this, brojacTacnihOdgovoraString, "Osvojili ste " + brojacTacnihOdgovoraString + " poena!", "1T3");
            }
        }
        finally{    // kada zavrsi sa koriscenjem baze podataka, zatvara db
            mDbHelper.close();
        }

    bIzlazIzKviza.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();   
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I tried placing this in my code, but it didn't work:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            this.finish();
    }
```

Also tried this, it didn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: If you would use English to name your variables and classes, your code might be understandable... to make the solution short: Stop/pause your countdowntimer when your activity calls `onPause()` or `onStop()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue us that the activity is stopped but the background threads you've created are left running. So you need to override onStop and cancel any background threads.

Something like:

```
@Override public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    brojacVremena.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent a = new Intent(this,"another activity class to go to");
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);//leaves no history of the activity and clears the backstack.
    startActivity(a); 
    finish();
```

Also have a look at this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

To learn about activity back stack http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. The combination of the link above should give you an insight of what you want to do to solve your problem